# Создать javascript массив объектов, который будет хранить в себе информацию о продукте

Tags: javascript, html

Создать массив объектов, который будет хранить в себе информацию о продукте:

- Имя
- линк на картинку
- рейтинг
- цена

```
var imageValues = []; // объявление массива

imageValues[0] = {
    name: "LEGITIM",
    link: "http://fozzyshop.com.ua/72653-thickbox_default/voda-mineralnaya-borjomi-evro-steklo.jpg",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}
imageValues[1] = {
    name: "bread",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}
imageValues[2] = {
    name: "milk",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}

imageValues[3] = {
    name: "water",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5,50$"
}
```

как вывести это на страничку ?

Вместе с картинкой

Comment: Что значит как ? вопрос немного глобальный , вывести можно разными способами , используя vue js , либо другой фв ,  либо нативным js , в каком виде , какие теги

Comment: Можно методом `arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])` или `.each(callback(index, domElement))` если используете jQuery

Comment: меня интересует реализация на  нативным js.

Answer (score 3):

Вы так имели ввиду?

```js
var imageValues = []; // объявление массива

imageValues[0] = {
    name: "LEGITIM",
    link: "http://fozzyshop.com.ua/72653-thickbox_default/voda-mineralnaya-borjomi-evro-steklo.jpg",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}
imageValues[1] = {
    name: "bread",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}
imageValues[2] = {
    name: "milk",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}

imageValues[3] = {
    name: "water",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5,50$"
}
for (var i = 0; i < imageValues.length; i++) {
  var element = "<p><h3>"+imageValues[i].name+"</h3>"+ 
                "<br /> <img src='"+imageValues[i].link+"'width='50px' height='50px' />"+
                "<br /> Rate : "+ imageValues[i].rate +
                "<br /> Price : "+ imageValues[i].price +
                "</p>";
  
  $("#output").append(element);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "output">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE: Без JQuery**

```js
var imageValues = []; // объявление массива

imageValues[0] = {
    name: "LEGITIM",
    link: "http://fozzyshop.com.ua/72653-thickbox_default/voda-mineralnaya-borjomi-evro-steklo.jpg",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}
imageValues[1] = {
    name: "bread",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}
imageValues[2] = {
    name: "milk",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5$"
}

imageValues[3] = {
    name: "water",
    link: "",
    rate: "5",
    price:  "5,50$"
}
for (var i = 0; i < imageValues.length; i++) {
  var element = "<p><h3>"+imageValues[i].name+"</h3>"+ 
                "<br /> <img src='"+imageValues[i].link+"'width='50px' height='50px' />"+
                "<br /> Rate : "+ imageValues[i].rate +
                "<br /> Price : "+ imageValues[i].price +
                "</p>";
  
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += element;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id = "output">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да
Это как раз то что я хотел. Спасибо

Comment: Хотел спросить а реально это сделать без jquery ?

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо очень помог!